# Dropdowns driven by ElasticSearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Currently have dropdowns used in a search component that are driven by ES using terms aggregations. A dropdown when selected should filter the other dropdowns but not itself any further. I am currently essentially doing two searches to accomplish this and collecting aggregations from both. first is size 0 with the given query excluding the most recently applied filters:

(simplified for the post)

```
  // for aggregation on last filter selected
var newestFilterResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<Index>(s => s
           .Index(_index)
           .From(0)
           .Size(0)
           .Query(QueryClosure(phrase, fields, filtersMinusLast))
           .Aggregations(FilterOptionsAggregationClosure(lastFilter)));

 // actual query for results and aggregation on other filters
var response = await _client.SearchAsync<Index>(s => s
            .Index(_index)
            .From(0)
            .Size(500)
            .Query(QueryClosure(phrase, fields, allFilters))
            .Aggregations(FilterOptionsAggregationClosure(allFiltersExceptLast)));
```

use below to build terms aggregations for each dropdown

```
Func<AggregationContainerDescriptor<Index>, IAggregationContainer> FilterOptionsAggregationClosure(List<FilterButton> filterButtons)
    {

        return delegate (AggregationContainerDescriptor<Index> aggregationContainerDescriptor)
        {
            foreach (var filterButton in filterButtons)
            {
                aggregationContainerDescriptor = aggregationContainerDescriptor
                    .Terms(filterButton.AggregationName, t => t
                        .Field(filterButton.FieldToSearch)
                        .Size(10000)
                    );
            }

            return aggregationContainerDescriptor;
        };
}
```

use below to build query (simplified to just filter for example, but there is multimatch, prefix and some more in my actual use case)

```
Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Index>, QueryContainer> QueryClosure(string phrase, Fields fields, List<FilterApplied> filtersApplied)
    {

        return delegate (QueryContainerDescriptor<Index> queryContainerDescriptor)
        {
            // multimatch, prefix, etc. on phrase for fields supplied
            QueryContainer queryContainer = GetKeywordQuery(phrase, fields);

            QueryContainer filterQuery = new();
            foreach (var filter in filtersApplied)
            {
                QueryContainer sameFilterQuery = new QueryContainerDescriptor<Index>()
                    .Bool(boolQuery => boolQuery
                        .Filter(f => f
                            .Terms(terms => terms
                                .Field(filter.FieldToSearch)
                                .Terms(filter.Values))));

                filterQuery = filterQuery && sameFilterQuery;

            }

            return queryContainer && filterQuery;

        };

    }
```

i feel like this is not the way. Any suggestions to improve on this would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up caching dropdown options in session storage, we wanted to have url params be able to generate exact state of page when sharing links but ended up ditching that with regards to filter dropdown state so we could eliminate the need to do the isolated aggregation on the last filter type applied